# Return all rows after groupby pandas (i.e. not a reduced number of rows that is the unique values for the group key)

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

The following code from the tutorials yields the following results:

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar',
                    'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo'],
                    'B' : ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three',
                    'two', 'two', 'one', 'three'],
                    'C' : np.random.randn(8),
                    'D' : np.random.randn(8)})

print(df)

grouped = df.groupby('A').mean()
print(grouped)
```

Result:

```
     A      B         C         D
0  foo    one -0.787410 -0.857863
1  bar    one  0.140572  1.330183
2  foo    two -0.770166  2.123528
3  bar  three -0.965523  0.771663
4  foo    two  0.215037 -0.597935
5  bar    two -1.023839 -0.248445
6  foo    one -1.377515  2.041921
7  foo  three -0.314333  1.379423
            C         D
A                      
bar -0.616263  0.617800
foo -0.606877  0.817815
```

However I would like to see all the rows as in the following:

```
0   foo one   -0.606877   0.817815
1   bar one   -0.616263   0.617800
2   foo two   -0.606877   0.817815
3   bar three -0.616263   0.617800
4   foo two   -0.606877   0.817815
5   bar two   -0.616263   0.617800
6   foo one   -0.606877   0.817815
7   foo three -0.606877   0.817815
```

I am open to use any other library as well. I just need to do this fast and efficiently using python3

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with specifying columns:

```
cols = ['C','D']
df[cols] = df.groupby('A')[cols].transform('mean')
print(df)
     A      B         C         D
0  foo    one  0.444616 -0.232363
1  bar    one  0.173897 -0.603437
2  foo    two  0.444616 -0.232363
3  bar  three  0.173897 -0.603437
4  foo    two  0.444616 -0.232363
5  bar    two  0.173897 -0.603437
6  foo    one  0.444616 -0.232363
7  foo  three  0.444616 -0.232363
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `apply`. Perform the operation on each group, but return all the rows of the group.

```
def my_func(x):
    x["D"] = x.C.mean()
    return x
grouped = df.groupby('A', as_index=False).apply(my_func)
print(grouped)
```

Comment: Thank you. Works fine aswel